# What are the prerequisite on the storage system side in order to use the DirectAccess services from Windows 7 clients?

Tags: windows-7, ipv6, direct-access

I would like to know what the cabling/protocols/storage prerequisits are in order to implement the [DirectAcces](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/enterprise/products/windows-7/features.aspx)s service on Windows 7 Entreprise clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to thank "SpacemanSpiff", who actually perfectly answered the question, by helping me discover a wonderful website called Google.

Though I'm using it in french (not the 5th link for me...), I was able to find [a website](http://www.infoworld.com/d/windows/microsoft-directaccess-ugly-truth-797) listing the requirements of DirectAccess. The rest of the article is also very interesting.

The following list of DirectAccess requirements comes directly from Microsoft TechNet:

- One or more DirectAccess servers
  running Windows Server 2008 R2 with
  two network adapters: one connected
  directly to the Internet, and a
  second connected to the intranet.
- On the DirectAccess server, at least
  two consecutive, public IPv4
  addresses assigned to the network
  adapter that's connected to the
  Internet.
- DirectAccess clients running Windows7.
- At least one domain controller and DNS server running Windows Server
  2008 SP2 or Windows Server 2008 R2.
- A public key infrastructure (PKI) to
  issue computer certificates, smart
  card certificates, and for NAP,
  health certificates.
- IPsec policies to specify protection
  for traffic.
- IPv6 transition technologies available for use on the DirectAccess
  server: ISATAP, Teredo, and 6to4.
- Optionally, a third-party NAT-PT
  device to provide access to IPv4-only
  resources for DirectAccess clients.

At least no protocol nor cabling limitations.